# Line number for Py_FatalError? ("deletion of interned string failed")

Tags: python, debugging, fatal-error

I am trying to debug a Python script running on the grid which throws a `Py_FatalError`, saying

```
Fatal Python error: deletion of interned string failed
```

Unfortunately, this does not tell me which line causes the problem and I couldn't reproduce the problem locally so far. Is there a way to find out more about the cause of this error?

(I cannot switch to a different Python version. For reference, this problem occurs with "2.7.9 (default, May 13 2015, 19:48:56) [GCC 4.9.1]" (output from `(sys.version)`.)

Comment: still a problem late 2017. Thanks for the line number @python